# attrs что это? Не библиотека

Tags: html, python, python-3.x

Что такое `.attrs`?

```
tag.attrs['src']
```

Comment: Обращение к атрибуту `attrs` объекта, находящегося в переменной `tag`

Comment: а что такое attrs? я ничего в документации не могу найти про него. только про библиотеку attrs нашел

Comment: `attrs` — это название атрибута. Само по себе оно не означает абсолютно ничего — это просто набор букв.

Comment: Указав название атрибута через точку, можно вытащить значение атрибута, хранящееся в объекте. Какое именно значение там будет — зависит от объекта. Какой у вас объект хранится в переменной `tag` — мы не знаем. Если это ваш код, то вы должны знать :)

Comment: в tag хранится тег от html

Comment: Это ни о чём не говорит. Любой объект принадлежит какому-то типу (классу). Тип (класс) обязательно лежит в каком-нибудь модуле. Знание используемого класса позволит (почти) однозначно понять, что именно хранится в атрибутах объекта. Есть десятки разных модулей для работы с html, и у всех них свои собственные классы для тегов и, следовательно, свои собственные значения атрибута attrs. Какой именно модуль вы используете и к какому именно классу принадлежит этот ваш «тег от html» — мы не знаем, следовательно, ответить про содержимое attrs ничего не можем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML теги могут иметь *атрибуты*, например

```
<img src="ball.png" title="A big ball">
```

Здесь тег `<img>` имеет 2 атрибута: `src` и `title`.

Атрибут `src` имеет значение `ball.png`, атрибут `title` значение `A big ball`.

`tag.attrs` есть *словарь всех атрибутов тега `tag`*, причём

- ключи - *имена* атрибутов, и
- значениа ключей - *значения* атрибутов.

И так ваше

```
    tag.attrs['src']
```

это значение атрибута `src` вашего тега (сохраненного в переменной `tag`).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88180/discussion-on-answer-by-mariand-attrs----).